# How to get public ip of an EC2 instance from aws CLI by instance id?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an instance that I start through aws cli:

```
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-00112223333444445
```

Instance does not have a static public IP. How can I get instance public ip through CLI knowing the ID i-00112223333444445?

Comment: Try this command: `aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $instance_id --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicIpAddress' --output text`. If the EC2 instance has a public IP address, this command will return it.

Comment: @krishna_mee2004 that works, thank you. Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: Sure, I will post that as an answer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try the following command:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $instance_id \
    --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicIpAddress' \
    --output text
```

If the EC2 instance has a public IP address, this command will return it.

Links:

- Details about the query parameter can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html).
- Details about the describe-instances command can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html).

Comment: Note on Windows you have to use double quotes `"Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicIpAddress"`